# HttpSessionBindingListener throws NullPointerException on TomCat server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, listener, httpsession

I'm using **HttpSessionBindingListener** to maintain a record of all active logged in users in a web application.The below code works well for WildFly server but throws **NullPointerException** on **Tomcat** in **valueBound** method while fetching the session attribute which was set before calling this method.

```
package com.abc.def.xyz.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingListener;

import com.abc.def.xyz.util.Logger;

public class ActiveLoginUserDetails implements Serializable,HttpSessionBindingListener {

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long usrId;
    private String usrCode;
    private String usrShortName;

    private static Map<ActiveLoginUserDetails, HttpSession> activeLoginDtls = new ConcurrentHashMap<ActiveLoginUserDetails, HttpSession>();
    private static Map<ActiveLoginUserDetails, HttpSession> loggedInUserDtlsMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<ActiveLoginUserDetails, HttpSession>();


    public long getUsrId() {
        return usrId;
    }
    public void setUsrId(long usrId) {
        this.usrId = usrId;
    }
    public String getUsrCode() {
        return usrCode;
    }
    public void setUsrCode(String usrCode) {
        this.usrCode = usrCode;
    }
    public String getUsrShortName() {
        return usrShortName;
    }
    public void setUsrShortName(String usrShortName) {
        this.usrShortName = usrShortName;
    }

    public static Map<ActiveLoginUserDetails, HttpSession> getActiveLoginDtls() {
        return activeLoginDtls;
    }
    public static void setActiveLoginDtls(Map<ActiveLoginUserDetails, HttpSession> activeLoginDtls) {
        ActiveLoginUserDetails.activeLoginDtls = activeLoginDtls;
    }
    public static Map<ActiveLoginUserDetails, HttpSession> getLoggedInUserDtlsMap() {
        return loggedInUserDtlsMap;
    }
    public static void setLoggedInUserDtlsMap(
            Map<ActiveLoginUserDetails, HttpSession> loggedInUserDtlsMap) {
        ActiveLoginUserDetails.loggedInUserDtlsMap = loggedInUserDtlsMap;
    }


    @Override
    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        ActiveLoginUserDetails sessionUsrDtls = (ActiveLoginUserDetails) event.getSession().getAttribute("LoggedInUsers");
        Boolean userHasSmInteractiveLoginAction = false;
        Boolean multiLoginAllowed = false;
        Boolean check = true;
        log.info("sessionUsrDtls:::::"+ );

        List<ActionDetails> actnDtlsList = (List<ActionDetails>) event.getSession().getAttribute("sessionActnList");
        for(ActionDetails actnDtls : actnDtlsList){
            if(actnDtls.getActionAccessValue().equalsIgnoreCase("smLogin")){
                userHasSmInteractiveLoginAction = true;
            }
        }

        if(userHasSmInteractiveLoginAction){
            String amultiLoginAllowedUserCodeList = "adminUser";
            String[] usrCodeArr = amultiLoginAllowedUserCodeList.split(",");
            for(String tempUserCode : usrCodeArr){
                if(sessionUsrDtls.getUsrCode().equalsIgnoreCase(tempUserCode)){
                    multiLoginAllowed = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if(!multiLoginAllowed){
            for( Entry<ActiveLoginUserDetails, HttpSession> tempLoginDtls : activeLoginDtls.entrySet()){
                 ActiveLoginUserDetails temp = tempLoginDtls.getKey();
                 if(temp.getUsrCode().equals(sessionUsrDtls.getUsrCode())){
                     if (event.getSession() != null) {
                         check = false;
                         event.getSession().invalidate();
                         log.debug("After Invalidating duplicate session for "+sessionUsrDtls.getUsrCode());
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
        if(check){
             log.debug("Inside adding user from session:::");
             activeLoginDtls.put(this, event.getSession());
         }
    }


    @Override
    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        log.debug("Inside removing user from session:::");
        activeLoginDtls.remove(this);
        loggedInUserDtlsMap.remove(this);
    }

}
```

It is throwing NullPointerException (for sessionUsrDtls object) at line

```
if(sessionUsrDtls.getUsrCode().equalsIgnoreCase(tempUserCode)){
```

which denotes that the attribute is not set into session. but this method will get called only after setting the value into session, so couldn't get what's the exact problem going on here.

Comment: Just a guess - perhaps Tomcat is also using the session and sets some attribute which triggers the listener before the _LoggedInUsers_ attribute is set.  Consider logging `event.getName()` to see which attribute triggered the listener.

Comment: Thanks for your suggession I used event.getName() and I got LoggedInUsers in return and still throws NullPointerException. And I'm not setting null value into session.

Comment: Maybe try using `event.getValue()` to see if it's not null.

Comment: event.getValue() did the trick. Thanks a Lot Andrew..:)